# Issue with queryset filtering with Django’s new Prefetch option

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to use prefetch_related’s new Prefetch option to further filter a database query. Using debug toolbar I can see that prefetch_related is doing its job in making the correct number of queries. However, one of those queries should be filtered to the current user, and I can see that it is not.

The goal of the below code is to show a list of Chapters. For each chapter, show its lessons. For each lesson, show the logged in user’s status (complete/incomplete).

The code that appears to not be working is in the view (setting the ‘chapters’ value).

**Models:**

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
    desc = models.TextField()


class Lesson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, related_name=‘les_chapter’)


class LessonStatus(models.Model):
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, related_name="status_lesson")
    student = models.ForeignKey(User)
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, related_name=“status_chapter")
```

**View**

```
def chapter_list(request, course_slug):

    course = Course.objects.get(slug=course_slug)

    chapters = Chapter.objects.filter(course=course).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('status_chapter__lesson__chapter', queryset=LessonStatus.objects.filter(student=request.user)),
    )

    return TemplateResponse(request,
        'course/chapter_list_parent.html',
        {'chapters': chapters, 'course': course,}
    )
```

**Template**

```
<div id="chapters">
    {% for ch in chapters %}
        <p>{{ ch.name }}</p>
        {% for le in ch.status_chapter.all %}
            <p>lesson status: {{ le.status }}</p>
            <p>lesson name: {{ le.lesson.name }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

When I run this code the LessonStatus is not being filtered by student=request.user. Instead, it is simply getting all LessonStatus records including those that are for other users.

Comment: related_name=‘les_chapter‘ is a typo?

Comment: The tables have a FK relation, so why not use select_related instead of prefetch_related?

Comment: DRC - That is an intentional abbreviation. Even so, do you think that field comes into play here? I assumed it didn't but I could be misunderstanding it.

Comment: Dan - I need to filter the related query even further. It is my understanding that you cannot do that with select_related. Will give look into it though.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I was structuring the 'chapter's queryset incorrectly. Here's what worked in the end:

```
chapters = Chapter.objects.filter(course=course).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('recchapter', queryset=LessonRec.objects.filter(student=student).select_related('lesson').order_by('lesson')),
)
```